# If someone comments in a mod election, there is no link to this comment from the "all activities">"comments"

Tags: bug, comments, election

Just noticed this bug in the profile of [bjb](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/20688/bjb568?tab=activity&sort=comments) on Graphic Design.

> [image]

As you can see, other comments do have link, but the comments left in the election page don't.